# Why are my variables not dividing properly?

Tags: java, variables, double

I have a problem with two of my variables not dividing properly.  I initialize all of them and they all work smoothly except for "yFactor".
Here is the snippet of code that is causing me problems:

```
        range = maximum - minimum;
        try{
            heightFactor = (580.0/range);
        } catch (Exception e){
            heightFactor = 0.0;
        }
        try{
            yFactor = (maximum/range);
        } catch (Exception e){
            yFactor = 1.0;
        }
        System.out.println(currentSavings);
        System.out.println(savingsBeforeRetirement);
        System.out.println(savingsAfterRetirement);
        System.out.println(minimum);
        System.out.println(maximum);
        System.out.println(range);
        System.out.println(heightFactor);
        System.out.println(yFactor);
```

The output of this code is

```
-318.3508771930617
10958
-318
-318
10958
11276
0.05143667967364313
0.0
```

Note that every variable above is "correct" for the parameters I am entering except for yFactor.

Here is my full code for this class, if you need it: http://pastebin.com/UnHUEdZM

Many thanks for any help anyone can offer!

Edit: max, min, range, savingsbeforeretirement and savingsafterretirement are ints and heightFactor and yFactor are doubles

Comment: What types are range, maximum and mininum?

Comment: Can you clarify what the type is of your variables, eg int and double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that range and maximum are of type int, so division will yield 0. This is cast to a (double or float) yFactor and will have value 0.0

Comment: Thanks!  It works properly now! I just assumed before that dividing ints would result in a double.

Answer (score 0):

Both `maximum` and `range` are defined as `int`, so with

```
 yFactor = (maximum/range);
```

you perform an integer division, which in your case result correctly with `0`.

If you want to have float-division, you have to cast at least one value to float:

```
 yFactor = ((float)maximum/range);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are performing division on integers which will result in a 0. Change your `int`s to `float`s or `double`s. Another option is if you cast them to `float`/`double` before division.

Answer (score 0):

From your paste bin, I see you have:

```
 int maximum;
 int minimum;            
 int range;
```

your division will be being carried out in *integer arithmetic*. That is, any fraction part will be lost.

To remedy, promote one of the numbers to floating point:

```
yFactor = (double)maximum / range;
```

The division will then be carried out in floating point.